# How to change fxml-variables creation pattern in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

If I have a variable/method in my fxml-file that undefined in my java-code and I create it automatically by alt-Enter, then I get a variable/method with public scope.

How me to change IntelliJ IDEA pattern for creating protected variable/method annotated by @FXML??

I have:

```
public Button btn;
public void onClick(...){
}
```

I want:

```
@FXML protected Button btn;
@FXML protected onClick(...){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **Default Visibility** you need in Settings(Preferences) | Editor | Code Style | [Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html) -> Code Generation tab.